# XGBoost modelling in Dask

Tags: python, dask, xgboost, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

My dataset has more than 100k observations and 120 features.I wanted to use XGBoost along with Dask Gridsearchcv to find the optimal parameters.But it throwing an error.Please let me know what im doing wrong

**code:**

```
import dask_ml.model_selection as dcv
import dask.dataframe as dd

pipe1=Pipeline(steps=[('clf',XGBClassifier(objective= 'binary:logistic'))])


search_space=[{'clf__n_estimators': [100,150, 200, 300], 
               'clf__max_depth': [4,6,9],
               'clf__learning_rate': [0.1, 0.01, 0.05],
               'clf__random_state': [0],
               'clf__subsample': [0.7,0.9,1], 
               'clf__colsamplebytree': [1.0, 0.9, 0.8]}] 

grid_cpu=dcv.GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe1, param_grid=search_space, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc', return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1,refit="AUC",scheduler='threads')

grid_cpu.fit(dd.from_pandas(X,npartitions=1), dd.from_pandas(y,npartitions=1))

print("Best parameters found: ",grid_mse.best_params_)

print("Best ROC found: ", np.sqrt(np.abs(grid_mse.best_score_)))
```

The X and y used here was originally a pandas dataframe.Im trying to convert it to dask dataframe before modelling.Im guessing that im missing something over there.

**Error:**

```
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-186-5a2967c1ae38> in <module>
     13 grid_cpu=dcv.GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe1, param_grid=search_space, cv=5, scoring='roc_auc', return_train_score=True, n_jobs=-1,
     14 refit="AUC",scheduler='threads')
---> 15 grid_cpu.fit(dd.from_pandas(X,npartitions=1), dd.from_pandas(y,npartitions=1))
     16 print("Best parameters found: ",grid_mse.best_params_)
     17 print("Best ROC found: ", np.sqrt(np.abs(grid_mse.best_score_)))

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask_ml\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
   1231             error_score=error_score,
   1232             return_train_score=self.return_train_score,
-> 1233             cache_cv=self.cache_cv,
   1234         )
   1235 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask_ml\model_selection\_search.py in build_cv_graph(estimator, cv, scorer, candidate_params, X, y, groups, fit_params, iid, error_score, return_train_score, cache_cv)
    201 
    202     dsk = {}
--> 203     X_name, y_name, groups_name = to_keys(dsk, X, y, groups)
    204     n_splits = compute_n_splits(cv, X, y, groups)
    205 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask_ml\model_selection\utils.py in to_keys(dsk, *args)
     85             yield x.key
     86         else:
---> 87             assert not is_dask_collection(x)
     88             key = "array-" + tokenize(x)
     89             dsk[key] = x

AssertionError:
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the assertion error my guess is that Dask-ML's GridSearchCV operates on normal numpy/pandas objects, not dask objects (I don't know this for sure though).  There is no need to add the `dd.from_pandas` calls that you have in this line:

```
grid_cpu.fit(dd.from_pandas(X,npartitions=1), dd.from_pandas(y,npartitions=1))
```

Instead

```
grid_cpu.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: Tried this. Didn't throw any error as before but the kernel crashes every time I run this

Comment: I'm unable to help without more information unfortunately.